# Cant get polymorphic model association to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a polymorphic model, but it still doesn't save, and gets into

> undefined method `notes_path` error

I was once able to get away from that error but still wasn't saving, and calling rollback transaction. Listener should able to create notes under messages and message parts. Can somebody help me?

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_notes, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_listener!

  def new
    @note = Note.new
  end     

  def index
    @notes = Note.all
  end

  def show
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create    
    # @notable = find_notable
    # @note = @notable.notes.build(notes_params)
    @note = @notable.notes.new notes_params
    @note.listener = current_listener
    @note.save
    redirect_to @notable, notice: "your note sas saved"

    # if @note = Note.create(notes_params)
    #   redirect_to notes_path
    # end    
  end

  private
    def notes_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:content)
    end

    def find_notes
      @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    end        
end
```

My Note model

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :listener
  validates :listener, :presence => true
  validates :notable, :presence => true
end
```

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for [notable, Note.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, label: "Message Title"  %>
  <%= f.button :submit, style: "margin-bottom: 80px" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller/message/notes_controller.rb

```
class Messages::NotesController < NotesController
  before_action :set_notable

  private    
    def set_notable
      @notable = Message.find(params[:message_id])
    end
end
```

My message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :speaker
  has_many :message_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :message_categories
  has_many :messageparts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notes, as: :notable
end
```

And my index page:

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <%= note.content %>
<% end %>
```

Updated!
My Routes.rb

```
resources :messages do
    resources :messageparts
      resources :notes
  end
```

Comment: Please provide your `routes.rb` as well as the stacktrace of the error which helps in understanding where the error is happening.

Comment: Ditto the comment about showing us your `routes.rb` and the stack trace that includes the error.  The error you are receiving is telling you that `notes_path` is undefined.  The issue is likely coming from how you set up your routes, or how you are calling them.